# How can I replace a CharField to ForeignKey using south in django?

Tags: python, django, django-south

**My task model:**

```
class Tasks(models.Model):
    state = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
```

I want to change the state field to ForeignKey like `state = models.ForeignKey(States)`

**Where States model would be:**

```
class States(model.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
```

BTW I am using **Django non-rel** with **django mongodb.**

Is it easy to do using south?or is thr any other way to do it?

Comment: I don't know about mongodb, but with mysql/postgres it's just a matter of running the schemamigration and migrate commands to change this.. it's very straight forward

Answer (score 1):

I will do it in six steps (migrations):

- First step a data_migration (south command): I create the States objects.
- Second step a schema_migration (south command): I add a fk in Tasks the name will be state_bk
- Third step a data_migration: Migrate all tasks and assigned the states to the tasks
- Quarter schema_migration: Delete the states charfield and create states fk
- Fifth data_migration: Migrate the values from state_bk to state
- Sixth schema_migration: Delete state_bk field

This is easy, but a little tedious

Comment: Hey , I guess South doesnot support MongoDB.When I try to run python manage.py syncdb after installing south it pops out an error "There is no South database module 'south.db.None' for your database. Please either choose a supported database, check for SOUTH_DATABASE_ADAPTER[S] settings, or remove South from Installed apps." ????