# Django South - Change Foreign Key to Required

Tags: django, postgresql, django-south

I changed my model from this:

```
class DistList(models.Model):
   creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='creator')
   created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
   description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
   company = models.ForeignKey(Company, blank=True, null=True)
```

To this:

```
class DistList(models.Model):
   creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='creator')
   created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
   description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
   company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
```

The only change was turning the company FK relationship from not required to required.

When I run the migration I specify a one off value that corresponds to the pk of the first company.

```
./manage.py schemamigration distlist --auto 
? The field 'DistList.company' does not have a default specified, yet is NOT NULL.
? Since you are making this field non-nullable, you MUST specify a default
? value to use for existing rows. Would you like to:
?  1. Quit now, and add a default to the field in models.py
?  2. Specify a one-off value to use for existing columns now
? Please select a choice: 2
? Please enter Python code for your one-off default value.
? The datetime module is available, so you can do e.g. datetime.date.today()
>>> 1
```

But when I run the migration I get an error because it has a pending trigger event?

```
./manage.py migrate distlist 
Running migrations for distlist:
- Migrating forwards to 0005_auto__chg_field_distlist_company.
> distlist:0005_auto__chg_field_distlist_company
FATAL ERROR - The following SQL query failed: ALTER TABLE "distlist_distlist" ALTER COLUMN "company_id" SET NOT NULL;
The error was: cannot ALTER TABLE "distlist_distlist" because it has pending trigger events
```

I'm not doing anything that seems weird from my point of view so I don't understand this error at all.  Can anyone offer insight?  I can post the full stack trace if it'll help but I feel like theres something obvious about south and postgresql that perhaps I'm missing?

Comment: You should see this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10462864/how-can-i-replace-a-charfield-to-foreignkey-using-south-in-django/10464035#10464035

Comment: Sorry, I'm probably being thick, but I don't see how that helps? Are you saying I need to run ./manage datamigration before I run schemamigration --auto?

Answer (score 0):

So I believe I've found the answer. I think postgresql doesn't like altering schemas and adding data at the same time.  I first created a datamigration:

```
 ./manage.py datamigration distlist add_default_values_to_existing_companies
```

Then I added this to the forwards method:

```
  def forwards(self, orm):
    "Write your forwards methods here."
    for distlist in orm['distlist.Distlist'].objects.all():
        distlist.company = orm['userprofile.Company'].objects.get(id=1)
        distlist.save()
```

Then I altered the model to remove the blank and null from company.

Then I ran the schema migration and chose to specify a one off for the value as 1 (as I did in the question).

Then I edited that migration file thusly:

```
def forwards(self, orm):

    # Changing field 'DistList.company'
    # db.alter_column(u'distlist_distlist', 'company_id', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey')(default=1, to=orm['userprofile.Company']))
    db.alter_column(u'distlist_distlist', 'company_id', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey')(to=orm['userprofile.Company']))
```

I just commented out the generated line and removed the default=1 arg.

I don't know... maybe this isn't right but it seemed to work.  Hopefully this will help someone.